# NGINX auth_request POST doesnt work with SSL

Tags: nginx

I am struggling to get a nginx auth_request to work with SSL.
http works fine with this configuration

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  community.foo.bar;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    
    location = /_token_check {
        internal;
        proxy_method      POST;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:2109/v3/user/community/token;
    }

    location / {
        auth_request /_token_check;
        auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_myauth_user;

        proxy_pass  http://10.164.0.69;
        add_header REMOTE_USER $user;
    }
}
```

Where my SSL config works for GET requests as it is supposed to be. As soon as I send an POST request, there is a 403 forbidden error from NGINX. **In this case my auth backend receives no request.**

I can bypass the whole issue by caching the auth_request responses, so for a POST there will be no call to the backend. This is still something like a hack and I would like to understand  the real issue here.

SSL Config:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl http2;
    server_name         community.foo.bar;
    server_tokens on;

    ssl_certificate           C:/Tools/nginx-1.18.0/nginx-1.18.0/ssl/wc-seepex-com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       C:/Tools/nginx-1.18.0/nginx-1.18.0/ssl/wc-seepex-com.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256-CBC:ECDH+AES128-CBC:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    underscores_in_headers on;
    ignore_invalid_headers off;

    location = /_token_check {
        internal;
        proxy_method      POST;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";

        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:2109/v3/user/community/token;
    }

    location / {
        auth_request /_token_check;
        auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_myauth_user;

        proxy_pass  http://10.164.0.69;
        add_header REMOTE_USER $user;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, what is happening here?

Comment: Can you share your error log? Try adding error_log /path/to/error.log debug; to the server{} context.

Comment: I will add the debug Log in one week, went in vacation :)